# Sort by taxonomy term name in Views?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

So I feel like I must be missing something obvious, but I can't find a solution to my situation. I'm trying to sort some nodes by the chosen taxonomy term name. This is Drupal 7, Views 3.

I have a taxonomy vocabulary 'Country' that is setup something like:

```
Asia
--Bangladesh
--India
--Vietnam
Afria
--Algeria
--Libya
--Nigeria
```

On the content type ('Partners') I have a taxonomy field called field_country. I happen to be using the Hierarchical Select module to make sure that, for this field, only the deepest levels are chosen (countries, not regions).

So all of that works and I can display the country chosen as a field in the view.

But I can't seem to figure out the correct way to sort by that country name. When I add the field_country field to the sort criteria, the ordering doesn't make sense. When I check the SQL statement it actually shows that it is sorting by field_data_field_country_field_country_tid. So it seems to be sorting by the tid rather than the actual term value. Although, a quick scan of the tid values shows that it isn't even sorting correctly by tid!

Here is what the SQL looks like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT node.nid AS nid, node.title AS node_title, field_data_field_country.field_country_tid AS field_data_field_country_field_country_tid, 'node' AS field_data_field_location_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_country_node_entity_type, 'partners:block' AS view_name
FROM 
{node} node
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_country} field_data_field_country ON node.nid = field_data_field_country.entity_id AND (field_data_field_country.entity_type = 'node' AND field_data_field_country.deleted = '0')
WHERE (( (node.status = 1 OR (node.uid = 1 AND 1  0 AND 1 = 1) OR 1 = 1) AND (node.type IN  ('partner')) ))
ORDER BY field_data_field_country_field_country_tid ASC
LIMIT 9 OFFSET 0
```

Any suggestions? Is there a magical relationship I have to activate to get the correct sort option available?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wow do I feel stupid today. I've done this before, but just seemed to have a brain issue.

Very simple:

1. Add a relationship for "Taxonomy: Terms on node". Select the country vocabulary.
2. In the sort criteria, select "Taxonomy term: Name" (I believe this gets added by step 1) and make sure the correct relationship choice is selected.