# Taxonomy jump list in view in parent/child order

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I have a taxonomy vocabulary of universities with their parent states. I then added this taxonomy field to the user profile so I could indicate what university the person was from. I'm trying to get this taxonomy vocabulary to display in an jump menu in a view (Drupal 7, Views 3) and honor the parent hierarchy, but the child/parent relationship is not being honored. This is how my jump list looks:

```
    California
    University of Georgia
    --Joe
    --Mary
    Georgia
    University of California
    --Mike
    --Jill
```

I'd like it to look like this:

```
    California
    --University of California
    ----Mike
    ----Jill
    Georgia
    --University of Georgia
    ----Joe
    ----Mary
```

I've read many [possible solutions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18341/sort-by-taxonomy-term-name-in-views) that suggest to add, "Taxonomy: Terms on node," but I don't even see that as an option. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "Content: Taxonomy terms on node" as a relationship.

[image]

[image]

Comment: "Content: Taxonomy terms on node" is not a option from which I can select in Relationships. Any idea why?

Comment: Your view is built on nodes correct and not users?

Comment: No, the view is based on users. The taxonomy is associated with users, that's why the jump list shows the taxonomy terms and the users who have that taxonomy term.

Comment: Any way to do this when it's based on users?

Comment: I created a user view after adding a vocabulary (with multiple levels) to my users and was able to get the terms from "User: FIELD", where field is whatever you called the field.